# Copying Files into Devel Space?

Tags: ros, catkin, devel, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My ROS node has some data files (specifically, GLSL shaders), that it needs to run. How can I configure catkin to copy these files over to the `devel` space from `src`, so that when `rosrun` or `roslaunch` is called, the files are in the proper place?

EDIT: Let me clarify. I have a couple of files in my `src` directory. My executable is assuming that these files are going to be in some path relative to itself (in this case, it is in the `devel`) directory. i.e, I have `"./some_path_to_file"` in places in my code. Right now, I manually copy these files into the devel space so the executable can access them. What are better alternatives to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202778/copying-files-into-devel-space?/) by [mklingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7191/mklingen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to copy any files from source to devel space. `rosrun` as well as `roslaunch` are able to find your files in source space if you reference them correctly.

Please post more information in order to get more specific help what might need to be changed in your package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mklingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7191/mklingen/) on 2015-02-09**:
I see. So I should, for instance, use roslib itself to find the files in source space?

**Comment by [mklingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7191/mklingen/) on 2015-02-09**:
Thank you, I simply used ros::package::getPath to find the files in the source space instead